# The Integration In Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

I struggle with integral notation in Quantum Field Theory , I see integrals like d4k/(2pi)^4 , but I dont know how to evaluate it! I think it will be good if I can understand the sign d4k and how to evaluate simple integrals in 4-dimension like in the picture
[image]

Comment: See in which reference? Which page?

Comment: Peskin (Introduction to Quantum Field Theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're integrating a multivariate function: The function is defined not on a line (like, for example, the function $f(x) = x^2$), but on a four-dimensional space, like $g(x,y,z,t) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - ct^2$.

That little $d^4 k$ is the *volume element*. Without getting too much into the weeds, this means that you break the entire space you're integrating over down into little four-dimensional cubes of dimensions $dk \times dk \times dk \times dk$, evaluate the function in the center of each of these cubes, and sum the whole thing up. Then you take the limit as $dk \to 0$ and hope the answer converges.

Practically, this almost certainly means you evaluate over each coordinate separately and in whichever order you want. You can do this as long as [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) holds, though most physicists I know just assume it holds and hope for the best.